# Understanding an integral formula

Tags: integration

This question has probably been asked here before so I apologize in advance if it's a duplicate.  I've seen this identity intoned in various contexts but I've never really been sure of necessary and sufficient conditions for it to hold true:
      $$\int e^x = f(u^n)$$

where $f$ is a real valued function and $n$ is a natural.  Is there a name for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Really?  This old chestnut?  At least be original.